# Right align for loop prints

Tags: c

I am writing a program that takes the 1st day of a month and number of days in a month and prints the relevant calendar.

If I enter 3 and 30 it should print

```
        1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24  25  26
27  28  29  30
```

This is the code I wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printclndr();

int main(){
    int first,days;

    first = firstday();

    if(first<1||first>7)
    {
        printf("%d is not a valid day. Try again. \n",first);
        firstday();
    }

    days = monthdays();

    if(days<28||days>31)
    {
        printf("Retry. Enter days for a valid month. \n");
        monthdays();
    }

    printf("\n");
    printclndr(first,days);
    printf("\n\n");

    main();
}

void printclndr(int day1, int numdays){
    int date,check,count,tab;

    check = day1 + numdays;
    tab = 0;

    for(count=1;count<check;count++)
    {
        if(count<day1)
        {
            printf("\t");
            tab+=1;
        }
        if(count>=day1)
        {
            printf("%d\t",count-day1+1);
            tab+=1;
        }
        if(tab==7)
        {
            printf("\n");
            tab=0;
        }
    }
}

int firstday(){ //function to get the starting day of the month
    int day; //initializing local variables
    printf("First day of the month (1= Sun, 7= Sat):  ");
    scanf("%d",&day);

    return day; //returns the value of day
}

int monthdays(){ //function to get no of days in a month
    int days; //local variables
    printf("Number of days in the month:  ");
    scanf("%d",&days);

    return days;
}
```

firstday and monthdays scanf user inputs and are working fine. My code works and prints the calender. Now I want to rightalign my calender.

I want

```
 1
 8
15
```

instead of

```
1
8
15
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Declare it before it is used, i.e. higher up in the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: conflicting types for ‘six’ with gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582731/error-conflicting-types-for-six-with-gcc)

Comment: @JCx Thanks.  Now it runs

Comment: Are you calling `main()` recursively on purpose?  Maybe you should just use a loop...

Comment: @Dmitri On purpose. To re-run after each successful run instead of closing the window.

Comment: Just use a loop, then... each recursive call takes a little more stack space (unless the compiler optimises it away).

Comment: `firstday();` you should post it too..same for `monthdays();`

Comment: @Michi Posted the functions

Comment: You can right-align a number like this `printf("%2d", day);` which prints it in a 2-char width field. If `day > 99` the format spec is ignored (the number is not truncated when there are more than 2 digits).

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane. Now I am getting a somewhat center-aligned result. Used double tabs and tabs with spaces and still getting center-aligned.

Comment: Maybe you want to put this one on code review rather than stackoverflow now? :)

Comment: @JCx This question does not belong on Code Review Stack Exchange as it is asking specifically for how to change *what the program does*. (right-aligning)

Comment: It started off as a different question entirely ... though still perhaps not suitable for CR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `"%2d\t"` and got the center aligned result.

Then I tried `("%*d/t",2,count-day1+1)` and got the same result.

Then I downloaded Eclipse on which with some difficulty ran all the codes including @WeatherVane 's and voila!! I was using CodeLite in my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

When you are printing the calendar use printf("%nd",number); n is a maximum number of decimal places, in your case n=2,   printf("%2d\t",count-day1+1);;

Answer (score 0):

This right-justifies the numbers as requested.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printclndr(int day1, int numdays){
    int day, count;
    for(count = 1; count < day1-1; count++) {       // initial padding
        printf("\t");
    }
    count = day1 - 1;
    for(day = 1; day <= numdays; day++) {
        if(count >= 7) {
            printf("\n");
            count = 0;
        }
        else if(count > 0) {
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("%2d", day);
        count++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    printclndr(3, 30);
    printf("\n");

    printclndr(1, 28);
    printf("\n");

    printclndr(2, 28);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
                 1       2       3       4       5
 6       7       8       9      10      11      12
13      14      15      16      17      18      19
20      21      22      23      24      25      26
27      28      29      30

 1       2       3       4       5       6       7
 8       9      10      11      12      13      14
15      16      17      18      19      20      21
22      23      24      25      26      27      28

         1       2       3       4       5       6
 7       8       9      10      11      12      13
14      15      16      17      18      19      20
21      22      23      24      25      26      27
28
```